# Send SMTP emails using Codeigniter on 1and1 host

Tags: email, codeigniter, smtp, shared-hosting

I'm trying to send emails via SMTP on my codeigniter website hosted on 1and1. It works well when i do it in local, but as soon as I try it from my 1and1 host i get an error.

here is my config:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'auth.smtp.1and1.fr'; //i'm in france and this is the SMTP server adress 1and1 gave me.
$config['smtp_port'] = 25;
$config['smtp_user'] = 'user@mydomain.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';
```

and here is the error:

```
The following SMTP error was encountered: 110 Connection timed out
Unable to send data: AUTH LOGIN
Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error:
Unable to send data: MAIL FROM:

from: 

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send data: RCPT TO:

to: 

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send data: DATA

data: 

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send data: //details about my message i removed
Unable to send data: .

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

Then I tried to use smtp.1and1.com instead of auth.smtp.1and1.fr. Surprisingly it worked but it took 30s to execute! (and on my localhost it is instantaneous).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talk to their support. They likely have restrictions on ports. Or use sendmail.

Answer (score 0):

If your Hosting Server and Email Server are Located at same place you don't need to go for smtp authentication.

so remove below code from your config file , keep everything as default and execute your functionality. Working for me. Should work for you in this case.

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'auth.smtp.1and1.fr'; //i'm in france and this is the SMTP server adress 1and1 gave me.
$config['smtp_port'] = 25;
$config['smtp_user'] = 'user@mydomain.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';
```